# How can I correct this Javascript for-Loop and array program?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I've got some kind of mental block while developing the code for this particular program.

Instructions to create a flexible marks storing database:
Ask the user how many students there are.
Using a for loop and prompt statements, ask the user for the student names. Store them in an array.
Using a for loop and prompt statements, ask the user for the marks (include the name of the class) for each student. Store them in an array.
Calculate the average mark for the class, and print it out on the screen.

It looks like got somewhere with the code but I've having difficulty combing the second for-loop to calculate the average of the marks of the number of students.
I believe the error results because I didn't declare all the necessary variables and also my array structure is wrong; like the way I declared and stored the elements.I think a few steps are missing from the code.

```js
var howManyStudents = 0;
var studentGradesAverage = 0;
var marksTotal = 0;
howManyStudents = parseInt(prompt("How any students are in this class?", "enter a number"));

    document.writeln("<p> There are " + howManyStudents + " students in this class </p>");

    var studentNames = Array(howManyStudents);
    var classGrades = Array(howManyStudents);
    var allStudents = Array(studentNames, classGrades);
    for (var i = 0; i < howManyStudents; i++) { 
        allStudents[0][i] = prompt("Please enter the name of the student.", "Student Name").toString();

         // reference a student Math grade
         allStudents[1][i] = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the student's Grade. The Grade are between 0 to 100. "));
     
         marksTotal += allStudents[1][i];
    }
    
    studentGradesAverage = marksTotal/howManyStudents; 
document.writeln("<p> Average per class is: " + studentGradesAverage + "</p>");
```

Comment: `marksTotal += howManyStudents` will always add the total number of students to your marksTotal instead of the entered grade. So you proably need `marksTotal += allStudents[1][i]`

Comment: @ChrisG nope. If you look at the (somewhat strange) datastructure, you will see, that `allStudents` is an Array containing two arrays, where `allStudents[0]` is the array of names and `allStudents[1]` is the array of grades ...

Comment: @derpirscher You're right, I didn't even check that :/

Comment: I personally would suggest a datastructe like `[{name: "student1", grade: 43}, {}, ...]` but that's a totally different story ...

Comment: The thing about this is that we haven't started covering material with that sort of data-structure yet. I'd like to keep the code structure as basic as possible.

Comment: That might well be that you didn't come across such datastructures yet. But believe me, your current structure will get you in trouble very soon. Just imagine what happens when you have to delete something. You will need to keep your (currently) totally unrelated arrays in sync, so that you don't assign wrong grades ...

Comment: Ok, I figured out the one mistake. In the array structure for allStudents, I made store the second index with i instead of an integer so it should have been allStudents[1][1]. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Here's a small rewrite: https://jsfiddle.net/3ayfk5wn/

Comment: Thanks for linking the rewrite Chris. Any amount of suggestions and tips always helps me learn better, appreciate it.